# configuring django-celery for database backend

Tags: django-celery

I'm working through the "First Steps with Celery" tutorial, and while I will move to a non-database solution later, I don't want to get into that now.  I just want to use the database backend that comes with djcelery.

So what should the value of the 'backend' parameter be in the following code:

```
from celery import Celery
celery = Celery('tasks', broker='django://',backend='XXXX')
```

I've tried:

"database" (which fails because SQLAlchemy is not installed)

"djcelery" (module object is not callable)

"djcelery.backends" (module object has no attribute "backends")

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie in celery and I wanted to use rabbitmq as the broker and djcelery's database as the backend. After much googling I found [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/celery-users/rmKODTaplD0) from where I derived the solution that works for me:

```
celery = Celery('tasks',
                broker='amqp://',
                backend='djcelery.backends.database.DatabaseBackend')
```

no alias used. Please, let me know if that works for you too.

Comment: How is this different from the OPs attempt (which failed)?